# Remove diagonals from a grid

Tags: arrays, algorithm, python-2.7, matrix, graph-algorithm

I am trying to create a height 5 and width 10 graph in python. So far I have this code which constructs a graph which has edges to the diagonals as well as up, left, right and down edges in a graph:

```
def construct_graph(data):
# initialize all of the astar nodes
nodes = [[ANode(x, y) for y in range(data['height'])] for x in range(data['width'])]
graph = {}
# make a graph with child nodes
for x, y in product(range(data['width']), range(data['height'])):
    node = nodes[x][y]
    graph[node] = []
    for i, j in product([-1, 0, 1], [-1, 0, 1]):
        if not (0 <= x + i < data['width']): continue
        if not (0 <= y + j < data['height']): continue
        if [x+i,y+j] in data['obstacle']: continue
        graph[nodes[x][y]].append(nodes[x+i][y+j])
return graph, nodes
```

How can I modify the above function to create only up,left,right and down links?

Note: ANode is just a normal python class which stores `x, y` for a node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `product` for the inner loop, just specify the neighbors that you want:

```
def construct_graph(data):
# initialize all of the astar nodes
nodes = [[ANode(x, y) for y in range(data['height'])] for x in range(data['width'])]
graph = {}
# make a graph with child nodes
for x, y in product(range(data['width']), range(data['height'])):
    node = nodes[x][y]
    graph[node] = []
    for i, j in [(-1, 0), (0, -1), (0, 1), (1, 0)]:
        if not (0 <= x + i < data['width']): continue
        if not (0 <= y + j < data['height']): continue
        if [x+i,y+j] in data['obstacle']: continue
        graph[nodes[x][y]].append(nodes[x+i][y+j])
return graph, nodes
```